# How to deploy an EAR file to wildfly-17.0.1 server with jboss-cli command using Java code

Tags: java, wildfly, jboss-cli

I want to deploy an ear file to wildfly-17.0.1 server using jboss-cli. I tried to execute the command using Java code but I'm always getting Error, here is my code:

```
Object instance = ReflectionUtil.getClass("org.jboss.as.cli.CommandContextFactory").getMethod("getInstance").invoke(null);
ctx = instance.getClass().getMethod("newCommandContext",String.class,String.class,char[].class).invoke(instance,"localhost:"+server.getProperty(SERVER_PORT), server.getProperty(SERVER_USER),server.getProperty(SERVER_PWD).toCharArray());
m = ctx.getClass().getMethod("connectController");
m.setAccessible(true);
m.invoke(ctx);
execute(ctx, "deploy " + earPath + projectName + ".ear");
```

I'm always getting this error :

```
"failure-description" => "WFLYCTL0158: Operation handler failed: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [core](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-maven-plugin/tree/master/core) utility as part of the `wildfly-maven-plugin` that can be used to programmatically deploy content. This would likely be a bit friendlier to use than reflection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need to use a reflection, I need to fix this error